# BBEdit grep: filter out specific character from results?

Tags: macos, grep, bbedit

From the following line of text:

```
ab•di•ca•tion
```

I want to produce the following line:

```
abdication  ab•di•ca•tion
```

(where the space between is a tab). This to iterate over multiple lines.

I can't find a way of 'filtering out' or excluding the • character from the results.

I'm currently using BBEdit on MacOS, but if someone can offer a Unix command line method, that would be equally acceptable.

Comment: "Needs detail or clarity." Really? I can't see how to make it any more apparent.

Answer (score 2):

We suggest the following `sed` solution:

```
   term="ab•di•ca•tion"; echo $(echo "$term" | sed "s|•||g") " $term";
```

or simpler:

```
   term="ab•di•ca•tion"; printf "%s %s" $(echo "$term" | sed "s|•||g") " $term";
```

And simpler solution with `awk`

```
    echo "ab•di•ca•tion"| awk '{a=$0;gsub("•","");print $0 " " a}'
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll play around with this to process every line of the file.